# Forms don't pass POST data between SOME pages

Tags: php, forms, post, joomla, php-5.4

The problem is that **some pages** literally don't work. It's a Joomla website, and for example login form for administrator section works, but forms for sorting or editing content on some pages don't pass POST data, while on others do. Problem is now in front end as well, and it is with form that was like that for past 2 years.
Website was recently moved to new hosting, with PHP **5.4** which required me hide some E_STRICT notices, but that's it.
I'm pretty sure that this new version of PHP has something do with it.

Here is the code for the page that is most important to fix right now.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>?option=com_jumi&fileid=7&Itemid=100&goto=jobsave" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="_self">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Category: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="jCat" size="1">
                    <?php foreach($cats as $jcat): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $jcat['pk_categorie']; ?>" <?php if($jCategory == $jcat['pk_categorie']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $jcat['nom_categorie']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Job: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jobCode" value="<?php echo $jobCode ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Title(english): </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jTitle" value="<?php echo $jTitle ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Titre(français): </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="jTitleFr" value="<?php echo $jTitleFr ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Description(english): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jDesc" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jDesc ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Description(français): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jDescFr" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jDescFr ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Requirements(english): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jRequ" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jRequ ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Requirements(français): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jRequFr" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jRequFr ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Schedule(english): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jSched" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jSched ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Schedule(français): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jSchedFr" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jSchedFr ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Salary(english): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jSalary" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jSalary ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Salary(français): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jSalaryFr" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jSalaryFr ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Application Process(english): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jAppli" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jAppli ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Application Process(français): </td>
            <td><textarea name="jAppliFr" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $jAppliFr ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Send CV to: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="jCV" size="1">
                    <?php foreach($users as $juser): ?>
                    <option <?php if($jCV == $juser['pk_user']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="<?php echo $juser['pk_user']; ?>"><?php echo $juser['nom_user']; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status: </td>
            <td>
                <select name="jStatus">
                    <option <?php if($jStatus == 1) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="1">Activate</option>
                    <option <?php if($jStatus == 0) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="0">Deactivate</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="" value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="jid" value="<?php echo $jid ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo JUtility::getToken() ?>" value="1" />
```

Again, this worked for few years, and since this update it does not pass ANY post data to the page.

Edit: Code that receives data, I commented everything else after it because it's irrelevant since on this first steps POST data is missing.

```
<?php
// jobs Admin
require('components/com_jumi/files/jobsAdmin/configuration.php');
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$css = JURI::base().'components/com_jumi/files/jobsAdmin/style.css';
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet($css);
jimport( 'joomla.html.html.form' );
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $_POST, true ) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Also I tried putting print_r as first, and it's still empty.

Comment: can you show us the code you're using to submit the form?

Comment: There it is, exact code in question. I checked it in Firebugs, Net panel, data gets submitted to the page. But it disappears somewhere in between.

Comment: The code you have provided is simply the html markup for the form. It uses `com_jumi` which obviously contains the process script for the form when it's submitted. So could you provide the code from `com_jumi`?